# Update multiple heroku apps by batch script

Tags: windows, git, heroku, batch-file

i have nearly 30~ heroku apps i want to update them by just 1 hit. i just made a simple batch but it doesn't focus to 2nd line after the first line is ok

```
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\app1 && up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\app2 && up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\app3 && up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\app4 && up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\app5 && up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\app6 && up.bat
```

up.bat =

```
git add .
git commit -m "update"
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`call`](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) if you want to invoke a sub-script and return to the main script after it completes.

```
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\app1 && call up.bat
cd C:\Users\Ofis\heroku\app2 && call up.bat
```